# Is it possible to limit choices in SelectModelField in wtf-peewee

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, peewee

I use flask with flask-peewee and wtfpeewee.
So, I have models like that:

```
class Category(Model):
    name = CharField()
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, null=True)

class Record(Model):
    value = DecimalField()
    category = ForeignKeyField(Category)
    user = ForeignKeyField(User)
```

When I create form for user to add Record, I do it that way:

```
RecordForm = model_form(Record)
```

All categories in database are available for choice in field 'Category' of this form, but I need to limit available choices for 'Category' field to a subset of categories that have user field equal None or current (logged in) user. I know how to limit it by query, but how should that be done for a form field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to see this just now

You can do this at class definition time:

```
from wtfpeewee.fields import SelectQueryField

class MyForm(Form):
    category = SelectQueryField(query=Category.filter(some_val=other_val)
```

Alternatively, I believe you can do this at runtime:

```
my_form = MyForm()
my_form.category.query = Category.filter(user=some_user)
```